# postfix/dovecot/roundcube: "Connection to storage server failed"

Tags: dovecot, roundcube

I have set up roundcube on a debian box per the instructions here: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_10&p=httpd&f=14

When trying to log into the web interface, I get a "Connection to storage server failed". When using the `openssl` command, I can log in remotely with the `a authenticate login` just fine. And when I select the inbox remotely, the mailboxes are automatically generated in the user's directory. So there has to be some disconnect between roundcube and dovecot.

This is the in logs about 3x for each failed attempt on roundcube:

```
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write key exchange
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client key exchange
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read change cipher spec
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, lip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, TLS, session=<wJBr4PCwYrQD5UF7>
Oct  5 18:44:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
```

Roundcube config:

```
$config = array();
$config['default_host'] = 'tls://example.com';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'tls://example.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$config['support_url'] = '';
$config['product_name'] = 'Webmail';
$config['des_key'] = 'abcd1234';
$config['plugins'] = array(
);
$config['skin'] = 'larry';
$config['enable_spellcheck'] = false;
$config['default_port'] = 143;
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';
$config['smtp_helo_host'] = 'mail.smartlu63.org';
$config['main_domain'] = 'smartlu63.org';
$config['useragent'] = 'Union Webmail';
$config['imap_conn_options'] = array( 'ssl' => array( 'verify_peer' => true, 'CN_match' => 'smartlu63.org', 'allow_self_signed' => true, 'ciphers' => 'HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3',),);
```

Dovecot config

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
verbose_ssl = yes
```

Note: I uninstalled the sieve package to try to minimized the complexity of the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Setting value `$config['default_host']` from = `tls://mail.example.com` to just `mail.example.com` did the trick. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the same problem and it was because DNS records didn't properly declare the URL's in the values of these settings:

```
$config['default_host'] = 'tls://mail.mydomain.tld';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://smtp.mydomain.tld';
$config['imap_host'] = 'tls://imap.mydomain.tld';
```

Once DNS recorded these, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

ROUNDCUBE: "connection to storage server failed" - Security Certificate Name Change issue

We got the same problem when we did an early update on our security certificate.  When we ran `$certbot --nginx`, it updated all of our certificates including one we had had a problem with, but then the cert had '-0001' added to its name.

So 'foo.com' became 'foo.com-0001' in all of our nginx config files.
Example:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/fullchain.pem>
```

...became:

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com-0001/fullchain.pem>
```

...in the `dovecot 10-ssl.conf` file.

This change of certificate name created a problem with both dovecot and postfix as their config files still had 'foo.com' [not foo.com-0001] for the cert names.  This led to getting the 'connection to storage ..." failure message.

#### Solution

Updating the cert names fixed it for dovecot and roundcube - obviously we also updated postfix!

This is a fairly obscure type of problem ... but it may help some future searcher!